# How to route requests to right tenant api gateway?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cloudfront, multi-tenant, amazon-route53

I am creating a multi tenant silo mode architecture to support a SAAS application. Following this [link](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/apn/building-a-multi-tenant-saas-solution-using-aws-serverless-services/).

I am able to register new tenants and create their respective stack like this:
[image]

So far so good, the next step is to create each tenant its own domain, for example: `tenant1.admin.foo.com`, to access the same CloudFront distribution (the web front end must be the same for all). I can make this by creating a record in Route53 `*.admin.foo.com` that has access to CloudFront

THE PROBLEM:

I need to route every request to their respective tenant stack, for example: `tenant1.api.foo.com/whatever` should route to the api gateway created for tenant1.

At first I thought of creating an origin in CloudFront that routes to the api gateway, the problem with this is that CloudFront origins are limited to 25.

I was thinking in creating a record in Route53 to point to their respective api gateway, but the problem is that I will have to use custom domain in the api gateway, because they are limited to 120, and I expect to have more tenants than 120.

How can I make this routing?

Here is an illustration of a use case:
[image]

PS: Any advice is welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can setup a distribution with a wildcard (*.api.foo.com) set for the Alternate Domain Name (CNAMEs).  If you attach a Lambda@Edge to the Origin Request (Under Cache Behavior settings), you can dynamically modify the host header to point to the appropriate API Gateway host (xxxxxx.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com).

AWS Blog where they did this, with S3 buckets for the origin.
It should translate fairly closely to APIGateway hostnames instead:

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/networking-and-content-delivery/dynamically-route-viewer-requests-to-any-origin-using-lambdaedge/

Comment: since i need to check a subdomian (tenant.foo.com) should I use origin-request or viewer-request? I need to get the 'tenant' part of the domain